# load resources according to users preference

Tags: android, string, localization, resources, runtime

I wanted to make android app which supports English and Swedish. I have gone through the localization concept. But i wonted to have two buttons on click on English button should load the strings according to English and on click on Swedish button should load the Swedish strings. how can i do this?

Comment: Yes, you can do this, but it would be quite silly to since Android's Settings entry for locale is exactly for this purpose. You would be creating a non-standard solution to a standard problem that has already been solved quite well.

Comment: It really should be done through the system settings but there are reasons to do it. In my case, we had to lock all other programs and system settings from everyday users. Since the devices are switched between different users, I had to do this so they could switch if necessary. Still could have worked around it but that's what the customers wanted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare two buttons, one for english and another for swedish. your code for `english en` and for `swedish sv` and then you have use [Localization](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html),this way..

```
            Locale myLocale = new Locale(lang);
            Resources res = getResources();
            DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
            Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
            conf.locale = myLocale;
            res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
```

check this simple [example](http://android.programmerguru.com/android-localization-at-runtime/) to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 1):

Sv=Swedish... en=English...
enter your language code in languageToLoad :

```
    String languageToLoad  = "Sv"; // your language
    Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad); 
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, 
    getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    this.setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is similar to others but I have added some extras that may be important

Warning

Everything I have read says that its not a good idea to let your app change the language because it isn't supported by the Android framework and it may cause problems.

With that being said, I have done it in my app and, while it has been a bit of a pain, it seems to be working so far. Here is how I did it in case you want to do it this way. You need a separate strings.xml file for each language. strings.xml in values folder as your default then maybe a strings.xml in say a values-es folder for Spanish strings. I have used the following code to change the configuration settings depending on a radio button that the user selects

`

```
final Configuration LANG_CONFIG = ChooseLocale.this.getResources().getConfiguration();
                    Locale newLocale = new Locale("English");
                    curLang = ChooseLocale.this.getLanguage();
                    if ((curLang.equals("English")) || (curLang.equalsIgnoreCase("Ingles")))
                    {
                        newLocale = new Locale("en_US");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        newLocale = new Locale("es");
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), newLangToast + " " + curLang , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Configuration config = getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration();
                    Locale.setDefault(newLocale);
                    config.locale = newLocale;
                    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = langPref.edit();
                    editor.putString(LANG_PREF, curLang);
                    editor.commit();
`
```

With this line being the most important to update the config

```
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

I get the local from my getLanguage() function which can be handled however you want. I also had to add

`@Override public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) { newConfig = Globals.getUserLanguage(this); super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);` to every activity that allows orientation change and add this to my onCreate() of each

```
final SharedPreferences langPref = getSharedPreferences (LANG_PREF, 0); if (Globals.langConfig != null) this.onConfigurationChanged(Globals.langConfig);
```

I also added `android:configChanges="orientation|locale"` to each activity in the manifest that allows orientation change. I store the users language preference in a DB that can be changed on the website or within the app. Hope this helps.